# (Application crashes) Null pointer exception in return ...when a method of public class is called from a Serilizable class

Tags: java, android

So When I call a method from Controller class to model class (which is supposed to return a String) it gives null pointer, because the method in Model class
is returning a null variable even it is filled.

```
public class HumLogController implements Serializable {
    private transient HumLogModel humLogModel;

    public String logIn (String username, String password ){
        this.humLogModel = new HumLogModel();

       // The line below is line 52. checkUser(username) is giving null pointer because Model class method is returning a null variable (I think). 
        if (checkUser(username).equalsIgnoreCase("correct")){
            this.username = username;
            if(checkPassword(password , username).equalsIgnoreCase("correct")){
                this.password = password;

                return "success";
            }
            else{
                return "Incorrect password";
            }
        }
        else {
            return "User do not exist";
        }
    }
    private String checkUser(String username){
      return humLogModel.checkUser(username);
    }

}

 /**   So when the checkUser(string method) call the checkUser method, it returns null,
    because the checkUser(username) method in the HumLogModel class is returning null. */
```

The HumLogModel class is....

```
public class HumLogModel extends Application {

    private   ParseObject customer;
    private   ParseObject tradesman;
    private   ParseObject user;
    public    String userSuccess ;
    public    String passwordSuccess;


    public String checkUser(final String username) {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
        query.whereEqualTo("username", username);
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (object == null) {
                    Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
                 // The value in line below is assigned in the variable.
                  // but it is not returned (I do not why :-( ) can anyone help :-( because I can not proceed without it.
                    HumLogModel.this.userSuccess = "incorrect";
                } else {

                    Log.d("score", "The getFirst request is success");
                    HumLogModel.this.userSuccess = "correct";
                }
            }
        });
            return userSuccess;
           // return "correct";
    // if the method returns  a hardcoded string "correct" directly everything works fine. but when it returns a variable userSuccess , it returns null...!!!! and I get null pointer. 
    }

}
```

The log cat is given below

```
    08-04 00:12:07.260    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
    08-04 00:12:07.472    1992-2007/com.example.praduman.humlog D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 312K, 4% free 8997K/9336K, paused 8ms, total 11ms
    08-04 00:12:07.476    1992-2007/com.example.praduman.humlog I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.database.Cursor.getNotificationUri, referenced from method com.parse.ParseSQLiteCursor.getNotificationUri
    08-04 00:12:07.476    1992-2007/com.example.praduman.humlog W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 491: Landroid/database/Cursor;.getNotificationUri ()Landroid/net/Uri;
    08-04 00:12:07.476    1992-2007/com.example.praduman.humlog D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    08-04 00:12:07.776    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
    08-04 00:12:07.776    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb9827de0, tid 1992
    08-04 00:12:07.792    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
    08-04 00:12:07.792    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
    08-04 00:12:07.848    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    08-04 00:12:07.848    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
    08-04 00:12:07.848    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
    08-04 00:12:07.848    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
    08-04 00:12:07.852    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    08-04 00:12:07.852    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 443: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    08-04 00:12:07.852    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    08-04 00:12:07.856    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    08-04 00:12:07.856    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 465: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    08-04 00:12:07.856    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    08-04 00:12:07.856    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
    08-04 00:12:07.856    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 406: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    08-04 00:12:07.856    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    08-04 00:12:07.856    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
    08-04 00:12:07.856    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 408: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    08-04 00:12:07.856    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    08-04 00:12:07.896    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    08-04 00:12:22.788    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    08-04 00:12:22.788    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c26648)
    08-04 00:12:22.788    1992-1992/com.example.praduman.humlog E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.example.praduman.humlog.HumLogController.logIn(HumLogController.java:52)
                at com.example.praduman.humlog.LogInActivity$1.onClick(LogInActivity.java:57)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-04 00:12:23.084    1992-2132/com.example.praduman.humlog D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 4% free 9184K/9536K, paused 14ms, total 14ms





/**below is the code and log when the method returns hardcoded string "correct" not the 
variable */


    public String checkUser(final String username) {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
        query.whereEqualTo("username", username);
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (object == null) {
                    Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
                    HumLogModel.this.userSuccess = "incorrect";
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "The getFirst request is success");
                    HumLogModel.this.userSuccess = "correct";
                    Log.d("After assigning value" , userSuccess);
                }
            }
        });
        // return userSuccess;
            return "correct";
    }

the log related to this method is given below

com.example.praduman.humlog D/score﹕ The getFirst request is success
08-04 01:05:19.240  24736-24736/com.example.praduman.humlog D/After assigning value﹕ correct
```

Comment: Is anything being logged from the if/else blocks? And have you tried debugging?

Comment: I did not undesrstand , what do you mean by logged

Comment: Oh,,, yeah 
the Log.d(....) in if / else block are working fine,,,if I put correct password and username,,,, the log shows
score : The getFirst request  is success.
else it shows...
score : The getFirst request failed

Comment: Which log message shows?

Comment: yeah yeah, the message in the log shows up according to username passed,,,, so the problem is not with ParseObject or with the Queries ,,,,
it is with the variable :-(

Comment: So , 
If I put a correct username which is present in Parse database table ...
score : The getFirst request is success...(which is in the else block)
otherwise 
score", "The getFirst request is failure ...(which is in if block ) comes up

Comment: Why not return the values in the if / else block?

Comment: because the if/else statement is inside void method which itself inside a inner class

Comment: try returning `HumLogModel.this.userSuccess`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried replacing the `query.getFirstInBackground(...)` with `query.getFirst(...)`? I could be misunderstanding the problem, but it looks like it might be firingoff the background thread to go process, then returning the null (unset variable) and THEN the background request is finishing, but it is too late, and the null pointer exception occurs.

Comment: Hey I have added the log when I returns harcoded "correct" in the return code.
i.e. The log I used for debugging.
So it comes up that the value is assigned to the variable , but when I return it it returns null.....

Comment: Thank you , 
I do not understand the problem, but your suggestion works

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the debug log entries from `HumLogModel.checkUser()` in the log.  My guess is that the method is returning before the callback is executed to set the value of `userSuccess`.  You need to wait for the callback to return before checking the value in the logIn method.

Comment: Hey I have added the log when I returns harcoded "correct" in the return code.
i.e. The log I used for debugging.
So it comes up that the value is assigned to the variable , but when I return it it returns null.....

Comment: That makes sense the `query.getFirstInBackground(...)` is processing correctly, just not before the method returns.  Try the suggestion given by @Oblivion.

Comment: Thank you 
you are right ,,,,oblivions suggestion works very well. :-)